# Query directory with CursorLoader

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursorloader

So this has been keeping me busy all day.

I am customizing a gallery in which the user can select one or multiple images, for which I am using an existing project which makes use of a `CursorLoader`. Almost every project uses the media gallery URI to query all images on the memory. However, I only want a specific directory to be scanned and the images within displayed.

Few lines of code which do partly what I want:

```
final String imagesDirectory = "/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/"
String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " LIKE '" + imagesDirectory + "%'";
cl = new CursorLoader(MultiImageChooserActivity.this, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, img.toArray(new String[img.size()]), selection, null, null);
```

The selection part of this code I found on SO as well, but it also retrieves all images in subdirectories, which I do not want. A solution could be to check whether the the `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA` column contains the same amount of slashes as `imagesDirectory`, which should work:

```
imagesDirectory: /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/                   -> 4
/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/photo.jpg                           -> 4, direct child
/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/subdir/otherphoto.jpg               -> 5, in subdir
```

I found that in SQLite, a query like this should work (to check the occurences of the`/`):

```
SELECT LENGTH(col) - LENGTH(REPLACE(col, '/', ''))
```

in which `col` should be `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA`, but as of yet I've tried a lot of different `selection` variants, but I haven't managed to filter the data. And since you can't give a `CursorLoader` a `rawQuery` (like a `Cursor`), I couldn't do that either.

Another thing I tried was to not use `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` as content URI, but rather a URI from the directory. So I tried this:

```
final String imagesDirectory = "/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/"
cl = new CursorLoader(MultiImageChooserActivity.this, 
    Uri.fromFile(new File(imagesDirectory)), 
    img.toArray(new String[img.size()]), null, null, null);
```

but to no avail thusfar.

**Question: How do I query all images in a directory, but not its subdirectories, using a `CursorLoader`?**

I'm no hero with SQLite, queries and `CursorLoaders`, so that might explain a little. Also, I did search SO for similar questions, but there's not much to find on this particular topic. Even Googling `directory cursorloader` does not answer anything. Most result are SO posts about sorting by directory...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it have to be CursorLoader? what gallery are you using and what are its input params (uri, cursor etc)?

Comment: @pskink Yes, it does have to be a CursorLoader. I can do the trick with a Cursor, but I used a GitHub project which uses a CursorLoader, so I can't use anything else. The Gallery is merely a GridView with ImageViews. The params are shown in my first code block (or I understand you incorrectly)

Comment: give me a link to that github project

Comment: @pskink https://github.com/derosa/MultiImageChooser/

Comment: if i were you i would write custom ContentProvider which query() method returns a Cursor, gallery's CursorLoader could use that ContentProvider

Comment: Without some sample code it'd be very hard for me to accomplish, for this is the first time I use Cursors, CursorLoaders and ContentProviders in an Android Project.

Comment: ok, before tou start playing with content provider, what about selection: DATA like [dir]/%.jpg and DATA not like [dir]/%/% (where [dir] is a directory to search pics in) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to pull it off by using an extended clause:

```
String where = "_data LIKE '/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/%' AND (SELECT LENGTH(_data) - LENGTH(REPLACE(_data, '/', ''))) = 4";
```

where `/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/` is my image directory and `4` is the amount of slashes in the image directory name. I've tried this on a couple different directories (and manually checking them), and it seems to work just fine.

I'll try pskinks method as well (`DATA like [dir]/%.jpg and DATA not like [dir]/%/%`), and report back the result.