# Getting a particular folders images in a directory using cursor loader

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-cursorloader

I m trying to retrieve images from a particular folder from sd card. what i m able to do is getting all the images from sdcard

code:
`onCreateLoader` method:

```
 @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE
        };
        String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
                    + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE;

        return new CursorLoader(getContext(), MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), projection, selection, null,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED + " ASC");
    }
```

Comment: hope it will help u:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410791/query-directory-with-cursorloader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I m trying to retrieve images from a particular folder from sd card

Pass  directory name as `selectionArgs` and change selection String  as:

```
 String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ";
 String selectionArgs =new String[] {"%PASS_DIR_NAME_HERE%"};

 new CursorLoader(getContext(),MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), 
                 projection, 
                 selection, 
                 selectionArgs,
                 MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED + " ASC");
```

Comment: thnku for your help but if i want to  get it from a sub folder from a directory

Comment: @HarmeetKaur: Try it by passing sub-folder name as PASS_DIR_NAME_HERE

Answer (score 0):

You can directly create Bitmaps from decodeFile (String pathName) that will give you Bitmap object that can be set on ImageView.

```
File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"iWallet/Images");
if(path.exists())
{
    String[] fileNames = path.list();
}
for(int i = 0; i < filename.length; i++)
{
     Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.decodeFile(path.getPath()+"/"+ fileNames[i]);
     ///Now set this bitmap on imageview
}
```